# Shap import python

Tags: python, numba, internals, shap

I am trying to import shap, but getting the following error:

```
SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
```

I tried solving this by uninstalling and installing again numpy and numba packages, but the problem still persists. How to resolve it?

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that you are using the correct command to install shap. Open a new cell in your Jupyter Notebook and run:

```
!pip install shap
```

Confirm that you are using a compatible Python version. SHAP might have specific version requirements. You can check the recommended version on the official SHAP GitHub page.

Ensure that your pip version is up-to-date by running:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
```

If the issue persists, you might be facing system-specific problems. In that case, you can try installing SHAP using the following command that includes the `--no-cache-dir` option:

```
!pip install shap --no-cache-dir
```